# Forward domain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have 2 domains and I would like to make the first domain use the second domain, for example:

> http://a.com
>
> http://b.com

Now, when someone will access

> b.com/test.php

it will actually use the file

> a.com/test.php

but, it will not forward it and the domain will show

> b.com/test.php

What's the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: You're looking to set up a **reverse proxy**. Look at the relevant `[P]` flags in the `RewriteRule` documentation...

Comment: You want this to happen only for some selected files, or the whole domain?

Comment: Whole domain, thanks

Comment: Then simply set the `A`, `AAAA` etc. values of both domains to the same reference.

Comment: Could you show me an example? I can't get it to work.